# What is the correct color notation in XAML: #555 or #555555?

Tags: xaml, naming-conventions

Doing **CSS** throughout the last couple years, I eventually learned that the standard way to represent a gray color shade (or any color which repeated its first three characters) was to use only three characters instead of six, I assume for terseness:

- ## 555 instead of #555555
- ## eee instead of #eeeeee

In **XAML**, however, I often see the opposite:

- ## 555555 instead of #555
- ## eeeeee instead of #eee

Are there any situations in XAML when one will work and not the other, or one consumes more memory, etc., or is this just a long/short notation issue and has no practical ramifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units) or [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980062(VS.95).aspx) both forms (plus more) are valid..

Answer (score 4):

**Neither notation is truly *more correct* than the other.** It's largely just a matter of preference.

The 3-digit format, or **`#rgb`**, is simply a short-hand format that expands to **`#rrggbb`**, giving you an option to leave out a few repeated characters.

```
#555 => #555555
#abc => #aabbcc
```

The exception is in specifics -- e.g., **`#e5a9bc`** can not be accurately described in or abbreviated to only 3 digits.

---

I would guess the common preference for not using 3-digit notation in XAML is be based in the fact that not all markup languages support them -- HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking I would say that the full six characters is more correct in any case as the abbreviated version is just expanded to a six.  Two bytes per RGB.

I also prefer the 6 digit as I am then able to keep things consistent looking.

Comment: From the W3 CSS link above: "The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00."  

Even though it's 8 bit vs 16bit, they're still the same color, and it's quite unusual to see 8bit desktop screens nowdays.

Comment: To correct myself, /in XAML/, the 3-char version is 8-bit, while the 6-char is 16-bit. Hugo's right that with CSS it's just replicating digits. Either way, of course that doesn't mean it's really going on an 8-bit screen.

Comment: Plus some tools (e.g. color pickers) generate only the #rrggbb. Keeping it all in #rrggbb makes interoperability a mite easier.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** whoops, completely skipped over the XAML bit. The stuff below still relates to CSS though. Sorry mate

---

According to the W3C, they've been the same since [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#color-units). I've not met a browser yet that'll display `#abc` any different to #aabbcc.

> gray color shade (or any color which repeated its first three characters)

I may be misreading your question, but you can do more than just gray. The hext notations are #rgb, or #rrggbb. So, `#123` = `#112233`, not `#123123` :-)